# React child component not re-rendering on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I realize questions like this have been asked before but from reading several Q&As here it seems like in a lot of cases people are recommending using `componentWillUpdate` but from my (very) basic understanding of React, if I `setState()` won't child components re-render if they are affected?

This is my App component (showing the State being set, the function to update the state `handleClick`, the Display component (which shows the current input from state) and a Button component which shows a number and is passed the function `handleClick`:

```
 this.State = {
      calcValue: 0
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(val) {
    this.setState({ calcValue: val })
   }

  render() {
    return( 
      <div class="calcBody">
        <Display currentValue={this.State.calcValue} />
        <h1>Calculator</h1>
        <div class="numPad">
        <Button btn="num col1" operator={1} handleClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />
```

This is the Button component:

```
    class Button extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }
      render() {
        return(
/*the button when clicked takes the handleClick function and passes it props based on whatever number is pressed */
          <button onClick={() => this.props.handleClick(this.props.operator)}>
          <div class={this.props.btn}>{this.props.operator}</div>
          </button>
        )
      }
    }
```

Lastly, this is the Display component:

```
class Display extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.props = {
      currentValue: this.props.currentValue
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <h1>{this.props.currentValue}</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm wondering why this does not update when handleClick(val) is called?

Comment: You set operator to `1`, so even though you update your state with `1` each time `Button` is clicked the props that get passed to `Display` never change. i.e. `this.props.currentValue` is always `1`

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I think I'm starting to get it but `this.props.currentValue` in Display is always 0 (which is what the original state is set to) if it turned to 1 when the button in Button was pressed then this would make sense but why does that not change?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that your initial state was 0. I would try logging out what `val` is within `handleClick`. I bet it is something you aren't expecting

Comment: Thanks for your help @HunterMcMillen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining state as `this.State` which is incorrect it [should be lowercased](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html): `this.state`:

```
this.state = {
    calcValue: 0
}
```

Also, this line:

```
this.props = {
   currentValue: this.props.currentValue
}
```

doesn't have much sense, as props are passed outside, [component shouldn't change them](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props).

Comment: Thanks, @Alex, this worked! I will remove that prop declaration in the component, being new to React I am still struggling to figure out what's required and whats not.